# Party package (ctree/cforest) in R with NA values

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data, party

I don't quite understand how ctree/cforest deal with missing predictors. Can someone please explain this further?

Answer (score 3):

Conditional inference trees (CTree) as implemented in `party` and its successor package `partykit` allow for so-called surrogate splits when predictors are missing. The idea is that if the original split, say $x_1 > \xi$, should be evaluated but $x_1$ is missing, an alternative split $x_j > \nu$ (with $j \neq 1$) can be used that approximates the original split.

To find this best approximating split a CTree is learned that has the binary response $x_1 > \xi$ and can choose from all remaining $x_j$ as surrogate split variables. This will find the best surrogate split approximating the original split - using the same criterion as the CTree itself employs.

This is briefly described in the original CTree paper in Section 3.3: Torsten Hothorn, Kurt Hornik, Achim Zeileis (2006). "Unbiased Recursive Partitioning: A Conditional Inference Framework." *Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics*, **15**(3), 651-674. [doi:10.1198/106186006X133933](https://doi.org/10.1198/106186006X133933) [[preprint]](https://eeecon.uibk.ac.at/~zeileis/papers/Hothorn+Hornik+Zeileis-2006.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one question, why is ctree default for maxsurrogate=0. What does 0 mean here?

Comment: At most 0 surrogate splits are considered, i.e., none. Simply for saving computation time.

Comment: So when the default is 0, how does it account for missing values? Do I have to change the default to account for missing values?

Comment: If you want surrogate splits, then you need to change the default: yes. If no surrogates are available (or have missing values themselves), then the default is to split the data randomly with the proportions from the learning sample. As yet another alternative the control parameter `majority = TRUE` can be specified which always assigns to the majority if there are missing predictors.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I understand. So when the default is maxsurrogate=0, it doesn't search for surrogate splits. If no surrogate splits are available, what does it mean " the default is to split the data randomly with the proportions from the learning sample"? is there an example here you can provide? I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding.

Comment: Say a split with respect to variable X with levels A and B was found in the learning data where 2/3 of the data go into A and 1/3 into B. Then you want to make predictions on new data. (1) If X is available it is used for splitting. (2) If not, a surrogate split is used (if available). (3) If no surrogate is available, the split is made randomly with probabilities 2/3 and 1/3. Alternatively, instead of (3) you can optionally always go with the majority (A in this case).